# Access one to many CoreData with predicate

Tags: sqlite, core-data, swift3, nspredicate

I have an one-to-many database (Questions--->>Buttons)
I am stuck here as I don't know how to proceed with this to access the buttons from my database:

I have the following code that I can get to my `Questions` Entity but I don't know how to proceed from here. Thanks

```
 func presentQuestionDetails(questionID :Int) {

        let coreDataStack = CoreDataStack()
        managedObjectContext = coreDataStack.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Questions> = Questions.fetchRequest()

         let myPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %i", "questionID", questionID)
        fetchRequest.predicate = myPredicate

        do {
            let results = try managedObjectContext!.fetch(fetchRequest)

            if results.isEmpty  {
               //empty

                print("empty")
            }

            else {
                let question = results[0]

               //do something
                print("got something")
                questionLabel.text = question.questionTitle

                for _ in 0..<(question.buttons?.count)! {


                    //I'D LIKE TO LOOP THROUGH MY BUTTONS HERE AND ACCESS MY "buttonTitle" i.e print(buttons.buttonTitle!)



                }

            }


        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Would that be the correct way? I am only guessing and would like your input. 
It seems to provide the right outcome but I am not sure if this is the right way to do it...

thanks

```
[...]

 else {
                let question = results[0]

           //do something
            print("got something")
            questionLabel.text = question.questionTitle

                let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Buttons> = Buttons.fetchRequest()
                let myPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %i", "questions", questionID)
                fetchRequest.predicate = myPredicate

                do {
                    let results = try managedObjectContext!.fetch(fetchRequest)

                     for buttons in results {
                        print(buttons.buttonTitle!)

                    }
                }

                catch {
                    let nserror = error as NSError
                    fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
                }    

            }
```